# finding points of non-continuity for a function with absolute value restrictions

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find points where the function is not continuous:
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} |x|-1 \qquad |x+1| \ge2 \\
2 \qquad \qquad |x+1| < 2
\end{cases}
$$
I simplified the restrictions as follows:
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} |x|-1 \qquad x \ge 1 \quad AND \quad x \le -3 \\
2 \qquad \qquad -3 < x < 1
\end{cases}
$$

So it looks like there're 2 potential points where the function is not continuous: at $x \to 1$ and at $x \to -3$. So I calculated whether we have a limit at those points:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^+}|x|-1 = \lim_{x \to 1^+} x - 1 = 0 \\
\lim_{x \to 1^-} 2 = 2
$$
So we definitely don't have a limit here thus the function is not continuous here. Regarding $x \to -3$:
$$
\lim_{x \to -3^+} |x|-1 = \lim_{x \to -3^+}-x-1= 3-1=2 \\
\lim_{x \to -3^-} 2 = 2
$$
So here we do have a limit. Thus the function is not continuous only at $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work is fine, yet the following is perhaps slightly shorter and clearer:

Observe that

$$|x+1|\ge2\iff x+1\ge2\;\;\text{or}\;\;x+1\le-2\iff x\ge 1\;\;\text{or}\;\;x\le-3$$

so in fact

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x-1,&x\le-3\\{}\\
2,&-3<x<1\\{}\\x-1,&x\ge1\end{cases}$$

And now it follows at once the function's not continuous *only* at $\;x=1\;$

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct to say that a function is not continuous at $x=1$, not $x \to 1$?

Comment: @Yos Functions are, or are not, continuous **at specific** points. There is no definition, as far as I know, of (dis)continuous *as* $\;x\to x_0\;$ . Of course, we're talking of points where the function is defined.